# Async/Await in multi-layer C# applications

Tags: c#, interface, repository-pattern, async-await

I have a multi-layered C# MVC4 web application in a high-traffic scenario that uses dependency injection for various repositories.  This is very useful because it is easily testable, and in production we can easily configure the repositories for specific controllers. All controllers inherit from AsyncController, so action methods that return `Task<JsonResult>` or `Task<ActionResult>` truly help our server scale with more users and [solve for the dreaded thread starvation problem](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4).  Some repositories use web services, which we can definitely use Async/Await to provide scalability benefits.  In other cases, some may use unmanaged services which can't be threaded safely, in which async/await will provide no benefits. Each repository is an implement of an interface, IRepository.  In short, each implementation is drastically different in the way it may get data.  This configuration is chosen at deployment-time with web.config changes and Autofac modules.

What are some of the recommended ways to implement async/await in an application such as this? To make the pattern fit in my existing application, I have to change the interface to return `Task<MyBusinessObject>`.  **But isn't this more of an implementation detail?**  I could provide two method stubs, `GetData` and `GetDataAsync`, but to me that wouldn't allow the flexibility I have now with IoC frameworks like Autofac where I can easily swap everything out without having to change code.

One of the Microsoft developers for Async/Await has published a blog post, "[Should I expose an asynchronous wrapper for my synchronous methods?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx)" that sort of goes into the problem.  If your async method isn't truly async (providing native I/O benefits) then it really only adds overhead.  In other words, it won't provide any scalability benefits.

I just would like how the rest of the Community has tackled this problem.

Comment: `async` and `await` are just abstractions for turning a blocking method into a non-blocking method.  You can do that anywhere in your code, without changing the interface, unless you want to force the interface method to be always asynchronous.

Comment: If you don't have Task<TResult> throughout the entire call stack, then it will NEVER be called asynchronously.  So you would have to put it in the interface to always return a Task<TResult>.

Comment: That's not what I said.  What I said was you can turn any method into an asynchronous one by using `async` and `await`, including any of those blocking methods you already have on your interfaces.  A `Task<TResult>` return type is not required on the original method.  It is, of course, a perfectly valid thing to replace all of your interface methods with their `async` equivalents, but it is not required.

Comment: That provides no benefit, it actually adds overhead.  Checkout Stephen Toub's blog post on it, "Should I expose an asynchronous wrapper for my synchronous methods?"  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx

Comment: @CyanLite: Your code can work asynchronously when you don't use Task<T> throughout the call stack, but in that case you wont benefit from IO completion ports threads, which seems crucial in your situation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your situation, I recommend making your interfaces asynchronous:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
  Task<TMyResult> GetDataAsync();
}
```

For synchronous methods, you can return `Task.FromResult`:

```
public class MyImplementation : IMyInterface
{
  public Task<TMyResult> GetDataAsync()
  {
    TMyResult ret = ...;
    return Task.FromResult(ret);
  }
}
```

Asynchronous methods can of course be `async` and use `await`.

Regarding the implementation details, I'd say "yes and no". ;) It's very similar to `IDisposable` in this regard. Logically, it is an implementation detail in the sense that it shouldn't matter which way it's implemented. It's *not* an implementation detail in the sense that the calling code needs to handle it differently. So I would agree that - logically - it is an implementation detail, but that the .NET platform is not sufficiently advanced to treat it as such.

Alternatively, you can think of it like this (which is the explanation I usually give): `async` is the actual implementation detail, and when you return `Task<T>` instead of `T`, you're defining an interface where the implementation *may* be asynchronous.

I have a [series of blog posts](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-0-introduction.html) that address designing with `async` "in the large" (i.e., fitting `async` in with OOP rather than allowing it to be functional). I address some common problems such as asynchronous initialization and IoC. It's just one person's opinion, but I'm not aware of any other resources for these kinds of problems.

P.S. You don't need to inherit from `AsyncController` anymore in MVC4. The default controller handler will automatically detect `async` methods by their return type (`Task` or `Task<T>`).

Comment: The link to your series of blog posts seems to be broken. Could you update?

Comment: Never mind, Chrome was being stupid and didn't "translate" the link correctly. Thanks for posting.

Comment: Actually, the link was broken; I changed providers earlier this year. It's fixed now, thanks!

Comment: Ahh, glad I mentioned something, then. Good stuff, BTW. Thanks for posting the blog articles. However, I couldn't find much on the use of DI/IoC when it comes to calling async methods and using injected objects (unfortunately, comment length limit won't let me be more specific, but any info on DI/Ioc and async you know of would be appreciated).

Comment: I've cover it somewhat in [this blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html), but in more detail in an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn683795.aspx). If you have a specific problem or question, you can of course ask it here where there are lots of smart people besides me :)

Comment: Ahh, Ok. I saw both of those. Thanks! I realized the answer had nothing to do with DI/IoC. I want to report progress. I found your blog article on the subject; that helped me immensely. Thanks once again!!!

Answer (score 2):

Task is a leaky abstraction. If you wish to benefit the use of IO completion port threads, you will have to return Tasks all the way from your repositories to your controllers.

Although making the whole call stack return `Task<T>` might improve scalability, it does add an extra layer of complexity to your application. This will hinder maintainability, testability and makes it harder to reasoning about code. [Asynchronous code will always be harder than synchronous code](http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2015/02/01/what-color-is-your-function/).

Personally, I rather increase the amount of memory of the server and configure the application to have a bigger thread pool to compensate the loss of scalability, or scale out to a few extra (virtual) servers, instead of adding this extra complexity.

Comment: I disagree regarding the extra layer of complexity. Maintainability, testability, and code reasoning are straightforward with `async`/`await` (once you understand them).